Finiteness of results in Connes-Kreimer approach
Remark: Although this is technically a physics-related post, the content heavily relies on pure mathematics, so I deemed it more appropriate here.
When reading the papers by Connes and Kreimer (e.g. [1] and [2]) on the Hopf-algebra nature of renormalization theory and the Birkhoff decomposition underlying the BPHZ procedure, they claim that the decomposition gives rise to finite renormalized quantities. Of course, I know that, in practice ,this is indeed true (BPHZ renormalization in physics would not be used otherwise), but I cannot seem to pinpoint where exactly this finiteness guarantee is derived.
For example, in [1], the authors claim that fixing the UV-divergent part in the $R$-operation is equivalent to it being an idempotent operator $R^2=R$. While in [2], the authors claim that finiteness is guaranteed "from the consideration of $m[(S\otimes\mathrm{id})\Delta(t)]$".
Is there a crucial insight that I am missing? (Aside from the fact that the regularization step, i.e. passing from $\mathbb{C}$-valued characters to $A$-valued characters for some Rota–Baxter algebra $A$, tries to fix the momentum divergence, but usually replaces this by a related kind of divergence in the regularization parameter.)
References:
[1]: Ebrahimi-Fard and Kreimer (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510202v2)
[2]: Connes and Kreimer (https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9808042)
